# Resource not found in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I start debugging the code and getting the following Error.
What could be the cause of following Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)
could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Main.aspx

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3655; 
ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3658
```

Comment: Is this an MVC application?

Comment: NO. It is ASP.net web Application.

Comment: Check if you have `Main.aspx` page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource not found Error in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198382/resource-not-found-error-in-net)

Comment: Well the error its pretty descriptive, `Main.aspx` is not found. HTTP 404 means that the Resource does not exist... Are you pointing to the right location? Does `Main.aspx` exist? Where is it located at the moment? Provide us a screenshot of your solution explorer.

Comment: Did you start debugging by pressing F5 or by attaching to IIS?

Comment: @HansKesting yes i tried debugging by attaching it to IIS.

Comment: @Dayan: i have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Main.aspx is available in workstation solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have Main.aspx or it is in one of the sub directories. Please check the location for the web form.

Comment: I am getting this error for all the pages. I tried other pages also as a startup page, but getting same error.

Comment: Do you have anything called Main.aspx in your application?

Comment: OK, right click on the aspx page in Solution Explorer and select browse. What happens? Also copy and paste the URL that opens.

Comment: Is this a valid URL as per your application?

Answer (score 0):

The application can not find the page /Main.aspx.

It could be that you're looking for it in the wrong location. Ensure it's located in the correct folder structure that you're trying to access.

Comment: I am getting this error for all the pages. I tried other pages also as a startup page, but getting same error.

Comment: @Nishant Try to gather more information, maybe a screenshot of your Solution Explorer?

Comment: What's the folder structure look like where Main.aspx is stored?